# Error when referencing requestanimationframe from object

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to call mozRequestAnimationFrame in firefox, but I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
var obj={
    animFrame:mozRequestAnimationFrame
}

var animF=mozRequestAnimationFrame;

function a(){
 console.log('a called');   
}

animF(a);

obj.animFrame(a);
```

The error occurs with the `obj.animFrame(a);` I get an error message of:

> Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

I found this thread on SO: [requestAnimationFrame with this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065169/requestanimationframe-with-this-keyword)
and then figured that maybe requestanimationframe didn't have the right "this" context, so I tried

```
obj.animFrame(a).bind(window);
```

but still got the same error message. So why is the error occurring?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140156/illegal-operation-on-wrappednative-prototype-object

Comment: I don't think my question is the same because referencing mozRequestAnimationFrame to a variable works fine and I'm not changing the function of it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know reason why you need to save pointer to `requestAnimationFrame` (`mozRequestAnimationFrame`) into some object, but try next code to avoid error:

```
var obj={
    animFrame:mozRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
}

function a(){
 console.log('a called');   
}

obj.animFrame(a);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I'm saving a reference to it for when they change it in the future and remove the vendor prefix. e.g. `if(!requestAnimationFrame){obj.animFrame=mozRequestAnimationFrame}else{obj.animFrame=requestAnimationFrame}`

Comment: Maybe is better to add next code into your js-files: `if(!window.requestAnimationFrame)window.requestAnimationFrame=window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback,1000/60);};}`