# How to wrap localStorage methods

Tags: javascript

I need to wrap `localStorage`'s `setItem`, `getItem` and `removeItem` methods so I can write something like this

```
local.set('foo', 'bar'); // equivalent to localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')
```

I used to do it nice and simple

```
local.set = localStorage.setItem
```

before I learned that [Firefox doesn't like this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140156/illegal-operation-on-wrappednative-prototype-object). So I changed my code to this

```
local.set = function() { return localStorage.setItem(arguments) };
```

but now I get an error `NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you, it works! Post it as an answer, would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
local.set = function() { return localStorage.setItem.apply(localStorage, arguments) };
```

Or for compatibility with older browsers you'd need to convert `arguments` to an array:

```
local.set = function() {
    return localStorage.setItem.apply(localStorage, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Your way was passing the `arguments` array-like object as the one and only argument to `localStorage.setItem()`, which means it was like doing this:

```
localStorage.setItem(['foo', 'bar']);     // wrong - one argument
```

instead of this:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');       // right - two arguments
```

Using the [`.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) allows you to use an array (or array-like object, though as mentioned above older browsers expect an actual array) to specify the individual arguments that should be passed to the function you want to call.